# Why is PHP option not showing in Languages and Frameworks in PhpStorm?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, phpstorm

I'm stupid. Let's just get that out of the way for the portion of people out there who will inevitably call me that. I'm the stupidest person to walk the face of the planet, and realistically I should go back to the zoo where I belong. However, in the meantime I'm having a problem.

This all comes out of me trying to edit my WordPress code manually and downloading it to use a debugger to see where the code is going so I can customize my profile tabs buttons, but the PHP option is not there.

**Any one know why this is?**

I downloaded and installed PhpStorm normally from their website, used the free trial, and didn't do anything else that should have messed it up? I did install PHP on my computer afterwards, but it was my impression that PHP came with PhpStorm somehow? I also installed XAMPP, don't know if that relates.

Anyways any help would be much appreciated. And I don't know what `php.ini` does, or config or whatever, I barely know what `htdocs` are or all of these fancy files. I can't seem to find explanations of them online anywhere that makes sense, but again I'm stupid so that's to be expected.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your PhpStorm Settings screen. Most likely the PHP entry will be at the very top (for a faster access: since 2021.1 version) and not under  "Languages and Frameworks" node like it was in the past.

Comment: *"I did install PHP on my computer afterwards, but it was my impression that PHP came with PHP storm somehow?"* No. It's your responsibility to get PHP installed and have it properly configured. As well as a web server and other tools. Your environment and requirements will be different to mine or another person (that's why Docker is a good choice in this regard). Although IDE can help you with downloading of some of the stuff (e.g. Composer / PHPUnit PHAR and alike)

Comment: *"And I don't know what php.ini does, or config or whatever"* see PHP manual for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php P.S. You have got XAMPP -- it comes with pre-configured PHP and should allow making changes there via GUI and not editing the raw php.ini. **Anyways:** I suggest checking PhpStorm docs for that: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-php-development-environment.html as well as https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/

Answer (score 30):

Just to amplify LazyOne's comment:

At least in my case it was missing because since version 2021.1 of PHPStorm PHP is not located under the "Languages and Frameworks" anymore. Instead it sits at the very top of the settings:

[image: PHP Language Settings]